# Make UIPageControl work the same on iOS 8 and 9 in right-to-left languages

Tags: ios, xcode, right-to-left

I would like UIPageView control to highlight the rightmost dot when its `currentPage` property is zero in right-to-left languages like Arabic.

**First page in iOS 9**:

[image]

It works like that out of the box in iOS 9 so I do not need to do anything. But in iOS 8 it shows the highlighted dot on the left which can be confusing for people who use right-to-left languages.

**First page in iOS 8**:

[image]

**Question**: is there a way to make UIPageControl highlight the rightmost dot for the first page in right-to-left languages in iOS 8 as well? I would like to achieve consistent behaviour when the app is run in both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to flip the control’s view:

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, it will flip it in iOS 9 as well, won't it? Which will make the iOS 9 version incorrect now.

Comment: Also, that will flip it for left-to-right language users as well.

Comment: Yes, you will have to check that you are not running on iOS 9 *and* also in a left-to-right language — which can be accomplished using ```[UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection```

Comment: You can check for iOS 9 by asking if the view responds to the selector semanticContentAttribute.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide some code examples please?

Comment: ````if (![pageControl respondsToSelector:@selector(semanticContentAttribute] && [UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft) {
    pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
}````

Comment: it's working well, the only problem is that it's not working for CurrentPage number, I'm still trying to figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 5):

iOS 9 includes significant UI changes for RTL languages. While it might be easy to flip the page control for a consistent experience, what about the rest of your app? It wouldn't make sense to flip only the page control, and flipping the rest of the UI for your iOS 8 users would be equivalent to reimplementing all of RTL support in UIKit – a major undertaking which will be difficult to get fully right.

I suggest just biting the bullet and only focusing on iOS 9. If you want to continue supporting older OSes, that's fine, but there's no need to attempt to replicate a fully flipped UI for them. iOS 9 supports all the same hardware as iOS 8, and users will get the flipped UI the moment they upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, the rest of the UI (the paged scroll view) is already displayed correctly for right-to-left users in iOS8 because I was using the Auto Layout with leading/trailing constraints. The only remaining inconsistency between iOS 8 and iOS 9 is the page control. I can not leave it as it is unfortunately, because it will very confusing for right-to-left users on iOS 8.

Comment: Okay then, no problem :-)

Comment: For me views flipping in ios9 is perfect but in ios8 it just changing the language not the ui controls

Comment: Yes, because RTL control support was added in iOS 9.